# Translate a URL into a PHP variable

Tags: php

I have this link which i need to "translate" in a php variable.

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=346824075388300&to=1149862205&message=Facebook+Dialogs+are+so+easy%21&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpenelope-ns.net%2Ffb%2F

I need to translate it in something like this:

```
$path = $protocol . '://facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=346824075388300&to=/' . $fbid . '&message=Facebook+Dialogs+are+so+easy%21&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpenelope-ns.net%2Ffb%2F';
```

Where instead of the value after I want to insert `$fbid` and i need also to make this a link, I mean all above is the link, I need to put it inside a href and put a word like, click here.

How can this be done?

Comment: I have no idea what I just read.

Comment: heh, my english, sorry!
i just need to translate that link into a variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really any magic greater than just concatenating your values into the string and placing it within the href attribute of an anchor tag.

```
<?php
$url = $protocol . '://facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=346824075388300&to=/' . $fbid . '&message=Facebook+Dialogs+are+so+easy%21&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpenelope-ns.net%2Ffb%2F';
?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Click Here</a>
```

Unless of course what you mean is that you are having problems getting values for the `$protocol` (usually http or https) and `$fbid` values, in which case I will refer you to the facebook developer documentation on how to construct an authenticated environment using their php SDK.